# MS Access Date Comparison Query Not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access

Dears,
I'm trying to check for records count within two dates with the following query

```
Select Count(id) As result 
From 
finished_tasks Where 
finish_date Between 
#06/06/2021# And #10/06/2021#
```

And i have a single record in the table with a **finish_date** **15/06/2021**
The problem is that the query above returns a result of 1 instead of 0
I have also tried to use

```
where finish_date >= 
#06/06/2021# And finish_date 
<= #10/06/2021#
```

And also i get a result of 1
I couldn't figure out the problem please help!

Comment: 15/06/2021 makes no sense. Slashes indicate mm/dd/yyyy. There is no 15th month.

Comment: @ErikA - that is the international date format used mostly everywhere but U.S.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use either the ISO sequence:

```
#2021/06/06# And #2021/06/10#
```

or the "reverse" US format:

```
#06/06/2021# And #06/10/2021#
```

Comment: Probably should note formatting depends on user's system time settings but the ISO covers all.

Comment: @Parfait: Yes, that's why the display format may differ from that to use in code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also functional forms with `CDate` in date ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) or `DateSerial` for fuller support of dates across regions with day-first (e.g., UK) or month-first (e.g., US) formats.

```
WHERE finish_date BETWEEN CDate("2021-06-06") AND CDate("2021-06-10")
```

```
WHERE finish_date BETWEEN DateSerial(2021, 6, 6) AND DateSerial(2021, 6, 10)
```